# How to take the median of the following a 4D array (31x6x2x3)?

Tags: arrays, matlab, median

I am trying to get the median of each row of the same columns of the following 4D array:

```
df = randn(31,6,2,3)
```

What I basically have is 31 rows (i) of 6 variables (j) for two shocks (k), all this repeated 3 times (n). Now, focus on the first shock and get a 31x6x3 array:

```
eg1 = squeeze(df(:,:,1,:)) %31x6x3
```

What I want to get is the *median of every row of the same column*: e.g. the first row of the first column of the 3 repetitions, then the second row of the first column of the 3 repetitions, etc. Easier to see like this:

```
% median of every row of the first column in the 3 repetitions

median(eg1(1,1,:))
median(eg1(2,1,:))
median(eg1(3,1,:))

...

median(eg1(31,1,:))

% median of every row of the second column in the 3 repetitions

median(eg1(1,2,:))
median(eg1(2,2,:))
median(eg1(3,2,:))
...
median(eg1(31,2,:))

% basically the median of every row of the same column for every column
```

This shall be done for either shocks 1 and 2.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Is `median(df, 4)` what you want?

Comment: @LuisMendo  does `median(df,4)` take the median of each row of the *same* column or it just takes the median, for example, of the first row of the columns from 1 to 6, etc?

Comment: @Rollo99 what it does is that for each `df(:,:,:,i)`, it computes the median. Which is what you want, seing your post. You will have an output of size `31x6x2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is the median of the last dimension. `median` accepts desired dimension as input.

`out=median(eg1,3)`

`out` will be a 31x6 matrix.

If you want that from all of the `egx`, you just want the median of the last dimension

`out=median(df,4)`